# Reflectively create an anonymous class

Tags: java, reflection

I intend to import a library(jar) using my custom ClassLoader and it turns out the requirement is there to set a listener on one of the classes, like,

```
Class<?> clazz = getInitializerClass();
Object initializer = clazz.newInstance();

// I would like the below listener to be set on this initializer reflectively
// setOnInitListener() is mathod to be called on initializer
setOnInitListener(new OnInitCompleteListener(){
    @Override
    public void onInit(){
    }
}
```

The issue is that I don't have the listener available as a import and all I can get is a `OnInitCompleteListener.class` dynamically by classloading on the fly.

How can I achieve the above?

**Note:** I am willing to go any limits to achieve the same but a simple approach would be appreciated.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : setOnInitListener() is a method that belongs to the type Initializer and shall be called on the same(reflectively)

Comment: is `OnInitCompleteListener` what's being loaded with reflection or is that what you want to set on the `initializer` instance?

Comment: @David : clarification added in the code

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : It is an interface

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous classes are compile-time artifacts. They even have names by which Java compiler can identify them, albeit inaccessible to programmers.

However, there is a work-around: since `OnInitCompleteListener` is an interface, you can produce a dynamic proxy that implements your interface:

```
InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() {
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.getName().equals("onInit")) {
            ... // Listener's code goes here
        }
    }
};
Class<T> onInitCompleteListenerClass = ... // You get this one dynamically
Object listener = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    classLoader,
    new Class[] { onInitCompleteListenerClass },
    handler);
// Use listener in the reflective call to a method taking OnInitCompleteListener
```

`MyInvocationHandler` implements [`InvocationHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) interface. Its `invoke` method can detect that it's being called in place of `onInit`, and perform the work as necessary.

Comment: This means that I have to import OnInitCompleteListener but this symbol isn't available at compile time. All I have use OnInitCompleteListener.class (and that too, loaded dynamically)

Comment: @pulp_fiction No, it doesn't: you can replace ` OnInitCompleteListener.class` with a `Class<?>` variable representing ` OnInitCompleteListener` class.

Comment: What I meant was the cast to OnInitCompleteListener in `OnInitCompleteListener listener = (OnInitCompleteListener) Proxy.newProxyInstance(`

Comment: @pulp_fiction You can make `listener` an `Object` since you are using it only in the reflection scenario. This would be an object that pretends to implement `OnInitCompleteListener` interface.

Comment: Okay. will try and let you know. Really grateful for your answer btw. Thanks

Comment: @pulp_fiction No problem! You are lucky `OnInitCompleteListener` is an interface, though, because you can't pull off the same trick with a class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `OnInitCompleteListener` class is available in the same classloader you're running the rest of this code in...

You can get ahold of the `setOnInitListener` method with reflection against the class instance:

```
Method setter = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("setOnInitListener", OnInitCompleteListener.class);
setter.invoke(initializer, new OnInitCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit()  {
        // implementation
    }
});
```

Comment: The issue is that none of these classes are available at Compile time(the symbol). YOur solution would require imports of teh above

Comment: Ah, if `OnInitCompleteListener` isn't available to compile against, you'll have to class-load it like you did in `getInitializerClass()` to get at it.  Then @dasblinkenlight's answer might be applicable to create a Proxy instance and set it into the callback method like described here.